# Design Android dev screen sizes

Tags: android-studio

Hi I need some advice/help

I am designing a app for educational purposes, but battling with different screen sizes.

I am using Android studio to create the screen layouts.

What I did so far works well up and until a point.

I have tried to use constraint layout / Linear layout and relative layout but all have the same issues.

I create my main layout as normal, and then I create new layout resource files with the same activity name but with different densities.

But for some odd reason some of my test phones picks up the certain density layout but is completely out of proportion, even though it looks correct on the layout on the IDE but the minute it is ported to the phone its out.

What would be the best way to create layouts that can cater for all layouts?

here is an example of the layout I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".login.LoginActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="10dp">
    
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_appName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="28dp"/>
    
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_appName"
        android:background="@drawable/input_shape"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittext1"
        android:background="@drawable/input_shape"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/edittext2"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_button1"
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edittext2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittext2"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape"
        android:text="Button 1"/>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_button2"
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edittext2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_button1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
    
   


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you are using a fixed size for your views.

**Never** use a fixed size for a view. If you are using a `ConstraintLayout` then set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of any view to either 0dp (which will make the view as big as it can be as long as it doesn't go past the constraints) or `wrap_content` (which will automatically make the view only the size it needs). On other layouts instead of using 0dp for making the view as big as it can be, use `match_parent`. `wrap_content` does the same thing in every layout.

Comment: By the way, Views are the objects that are inside the ConstraintLayout or other layouts

Comment: Should you have different density layouts or just one?

Comment: @RPN The ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout are just a few examples of layouts. The _objects_ that you put in the layout such as EditText, ImageView, Button and many others are called views. Now, what do you mean by different density layouts?

Comment: When you create new layout resource files based on the main layout you can select the density and then select xxhdpi layouts from there.

I dont know what the correct way is to create layouts as all courses only focus on the IDE layout and never touch base on multiple layouts for different screen sizes.

Should you only create one layout the default one that comes along with the activity you create and use Wrap or match to create the layouts?

Comment: For every activity there is only ONE layout resource file and ONE Java class. For MainActivity.java there will be a correspondent layout resource file in the res/layout folder. You only use multiple layouts for one activity when you are doing more advanced stuff. Android handles every resolution and density correctly as long as you use match_parent, wrap_content or 0dp for ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.

Much appreciated for the help.
I will try and let you know.

Comment: Last question.
How do you space objects in the layout without shifting everything beyond the layout?

In other words if I need to space the first object to the middle of the screen and everything below it is there an easy way because margin top shifts everything past the layout on different devices.

Comment: @RPN sorry for my late response, I am in Europe and it was late when you posted the question. In a ConstraintLayout, if you want to put a view in the middle of the screen, you constraint it to the top, bottom, left and right edges of the ConstraintLayout. Then, if you want to put a view above it, you can constraint it to the left and right of the ConstraintLayout and the bottom to the view in the center. Do the same for views below the middle view, except constraint the top to the bottom of the center view. Remember, you can constraint multiple objects any of the sides of a view!